# Can't pass array into Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a REST endpoint. When I access this endpoint through the DRF GUI, I can manually enter my data and it works successfully. My model looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    content     = HTMLField()
    created_at  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    authors     = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

My serializer and view looks like this:

```
class CreatePostSerializer(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'authors')
```

When I actually try to submit my data through Ajax to the endpoint, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/save-post/',
    data: {
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": getCookie('csrftoken'),
    "title": "dasf",
    "desct": "dasf",
    "content": "fdasf",
    "authors": [1,2]
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

I get an error that says: `{"authors":["This list may not be empty."]}` with a payload sending:

```
title: dasf
desct: dasf
content: fdasf
authors[]: 1
```

I've tried changing the contentType to application/json, I've tried almost everything but it seems like nothing is working. How can I make it so my endpoint understands what I'm sending?

Answer (score 0):

```
var authors = [];
authors[0] = 1;
authors[1] = 2;

var arr = {
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": getCookie('csrftoken'),
    "title": "dasf",
    "desct": "dasf",
    "content": "fdasf",
    "authors": authors
    };

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/save-post/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: arr,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: With this approach, I am getting an error that says `{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}`

Comment: @user2896120 try including `"csrfmiddlewaretoken": getCookie('csrftoken')` in the above ajax request like you did in the sample you posted in your question.

Comment: I did, i didnt change anything. I just added the JSON.stringify to the data

Comment: @user2896120 Can you please add the template code as well. where you are making the POST request.

Comment: @user2896120 I have done some changes. Please check.

Comment: Getting this error: `{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}`